# symmetricds sym_outgoing_batch.node_id=-1

Tags: symmetricds

There are two batch message in `sym_outgoing_batch` and one of the `node_id` is `000` (corp) another is `-1` (what's this -1 means?) when I pull many data from store to corp. Part of data is successful to router timely but other is delayed. The message is as follows:
[image]

and the configuration file is as follows:

```
insert into sym_channel(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)

    values('sale_channel', 1, 1000000, 1, 'sale data from store to corp');

insert into sym_trigger(trigger_id, source_table_name, channel_id, last_update_time, create_time)

    values('sale_pay_triger', 'D_T_BILL_PAY', 'sale_channel', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_router(router_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, router_type,router_expression, create_time, last_update_time)

    values('store_2_corp_sheftnotnull', 'store', 'corp', 'bsh', 'CSHIFT_C!=null && !CSHIFT_C.equals("")',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_trigger_router(trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, last_update_time, create_time)

    values('sale_pay_triger', 'store_2_corp_sheftnotnull', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into SYM_CONFLICT(CONFLICT_ID,SOURCE_NODE_GROUP_ID,TARGET_NODE_GROUP_ID,DETECT_TYPE,RESOLVE_TYPE,PING_BACK,CREATE_TIME,LAST_UPDATE_TIME)

    values('conflict_fallback', 'corp', 'store', 'USE_PK_DATA', 'FALLBACK', 'OFF', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
commit;
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why it's delayed and how to solve this problem.

Comment: when pull many data,part would be delayed

Comment: We'll that's expected and normal. Are there any errors?

Comment: ah.are there any tags that i could according the tag to make sure all data have been routed?Sometimes delay for a long time(Up to 12 hours),and I want to use this data before route completed.

Comment: Check the tables sym_outgoin_batch and sym_data_evet

Comment: as screenshot show,node_id of batch 26922 is -1,means that data was un_routed.But data what belongs to 26922 will routed delay for a long time,and there is no message show this data routed in sym_outgoing_batch or sym_daya_event,would you like give more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking what does a node_id of -1 mean.  It means that the data was un-routed.  There were no nodes that met the routing condition.

Comment: but some data is successful on a same machine at same time as screenshot show